# cannot "npm install truffle-hdwallet-provider" succesfully

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, wallets

The install fails. Problems seems to be the request to: https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git

**The error message is:**

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! error: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version while accessing https://github.com/debris/bignumber.js.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
npm ERR! fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Do you know cause and action to solve it?

Comment: Which version of git are you using? Also during installation it offers two options for SSL library, you can try switching between them.

Answer (score 1):

@Joel,,Issue was resolved after the updating the git to latest version.
I was using an old version 1.8.6 and after updating to latest version 2.16.2, the issue got resolved.